# SD Card keeps getting unmounted on my HTC Desire

Tags: htc-desire, external-sd

The SD card in my HTC Desire keeps getting unmounted every now and then and it's very annoying. From what I'm seeing, the SD card is removed only when some kind of multi-tasking with the files on it happens.

Example - Listening to a song that's stored on the SD + Using an app that's stored on the SD.

I haven't rooted my phone and don't intend on doing it. The phone is currently on the official Android 2.3.3 build.

I've tried another SD card but the problem still persists.

It's still under warranty, but I thought I can fix it myself with some help from you guys. :)

Comment: Which SD Cards have you tried? (make, model, size)

Comment: Hmm, recently had my card spontaneously unmount, and die as it turns out. Would like to hear from others with similar experiences. Not rooted Desire HD, running 2.3.3 here.

Comment: When this happens, is it plugged into a computer via USB?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the same phone I can fix it by formatting the card but I'm getting tired of re-installing my apps every few days

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with cheap sd cards from ebay doing this, I spend a little more these days on them.

There isn't much you can do here if you don't intend on rooting the phone or anything. If it was mine I would wipe the thing and re-install a fresh stable rom and test that for a few days.

Comment: You mean to say there is problem with stock ROM?

Comment: @roxan yes there may be some kind of corruption in the stock rom as the user has tried multiple sd cards, it would be easy to test this by installing a fresh stable rom on the phone with an image recovery, HTC support may even do this very thing with a stock rom.

Comment: Wouldn't factory reset be the better option?

Comment: Sure that is just in the settings but as far as I know it just deletes all the user data and may be unlikely to affect something like fix the sd card like this, worth a try I guess. Its not the same as installing a totally new rom and kernel.

Answer (score 2):

A friend had a similar problem playing mp3 in his car with a slow card. Try at least a speed 4 card. The speed of the card is shown inside a small, unclosed circle on the card.

For reference, I just bought a 16gb speed 10 microsd card from Amazon for $22.

Answer (score 1):

**If your phone is connected to PC** then might be getting chances of not detecting SD Card in Phone.

Try to change setting for removable device like below

- Drag Down Status Bar and select **USB Connection** Option
- if you are getting option like **Windows Media Sync, USB Mass Storage , None** then Select None
- Go to Phone Setting --> Applications --> Development --> and Uncheck **USB Debugging**

Try this,
it may help you..

Comment: Its not happening while connected to computer.

Answer (score 1):

And don't forget. If none of the previous answers seemed useful try formatting the SD card and delete any existing partitions using Linux Disk utility.

Answer (score 1):

I am an authorized dealer for metro PCS and we have to warranty out the device as this Is a hardware error from the manufacturer. It happens every now and then. So take your device(s) to your local dealer and warranty your phone. No matter of rooting will help this as it is a hardware defect.

Answer (score 0):

We bought a new Epic 4G for my mom a while back, and her SD would do the same thing. Just randomly unmount. Turns out it was a hardware issue, and they replaced the phone and the SD card. Sorry, but you might be out of luck :/