# How to fix - SD card works intermittently, rest of the time checks for errors

Tags: htc-desire, external-sd, data-transfer

I bought a new 16GB micro SD card for my HTC Desire to replace the 4GB one it came with. I copied the contents of the old SD card to the new one and my phone loaded just fine.

Then, every few hours, the SD card would unmount saying the SD card was damaged. Turning the phone on and off a few times would result in SD card either saying "checking for errors" permanently or, occasionally, working just fine for a while.

I read a little about it and saw that perhaps I should format the card on the phone itself. So I did that (via ClockworkMod Recovery and then again in the OS itself) and recopied the files. It seemed to work for a while longer, but has now again started saying the SD card is damaged.

The SD card works fine when I put it into an adaptor and into my laptop.

Could the SD card really be damaged? Is there some other formatting I should try? Should I try making multiple partitions or something? Any ideas?

My phone runs CyanogenMod 7.2 (based on Android 2.3.7).

Comment: Please also check the Q&As mentioned in the "Linked" section at the right: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25278/fix-a-damaged-microsd-card plus http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7289/micro-sd-card-physically-damaged as well as maybe http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14918/sd-card-keeps-getting-unmounted-on-my-htc-desire plus http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/how-to-fix-damaged-sd-card

Comment: I never fixed this - ended up changing my phone recently and the card works absolutely fine in the new S3.

Comment: That's quite strange, as it shouldn't be connected (I mean, what has charging to do with errors on the sdcard?). But if the problem no longer exists: Glad for you! And no way to figure out what it was, as we cannot check anymore...

Comment: Have you ever tried another SDCard at that phone? Maybe the problem was with the phone itself. Anyway, I'm voting to close as "to localized" since one cannot help anymore.

Comment: @Izzy I said chaNging not chaRging :) I don't use the Desire anymore, just my new S3 with the SD card in.

Comment: @Zuul Yes, it had a 4GB one in there and that was fine. I'm happy for this to be closed because I can't test the potential resolutions any more.

Comment: Sometimes it's really strange. I had a similar problem with my Droid 2 when switching to a 16GB card: Freeze, hang, reboot. Old card (8GB) worked fine. Updated ROM from stock 2.2.2 to CM7.2 -- now the 8GB had problems, but the 16GB was working smoothly. Which was fine with me...