# Fix a damaged microsd card?

Tags: external-sd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“SD card is damaged - You may have to reformat.” How do I fix this problem?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3963/sd-card-is-damaged-you-may-have-to-reformat-how-do-i-fix-this-problem)

I have a Sprint Kyocera Echo.

I accidentally pulled out the micro-sdhc card when in use. When I put the card back into my smartphone, it said "*Damaged SD card, you may need to reformat it*". When I pulled down the notification bar, it gave me the option to format my SD card, with a warning also of losing all my data. I formatted it and it said "*erasing sd card*", finally, a message "*SD card is currently being checked*" appeared.

When I placed the micro-sd card into a SD card adapter and put it in the digital camera, nothing seemed wrong. My camera took pictures like normal and made no complaints about insufficient memory. The logic is in to see, how the camera would react.

I put the SD card adapter into my computer and it read normally. My computer fully recognized my micro-sd and the files, along with the pictures I had just taken on my digital camera.

I took it out and placed it back into my phone, yet my phone still popped up with "*Damaged sd card*" message. I put the card back into my computer and formatted it through the PC, saying it successfully reformatted my card. I think its fixed or so I thought.

But no, still "*Damaged SD card*" error message on my phone.